# Echo a php function in a javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have the following javascript

```
function showIt(item,i,j,max){
  var id;
  actualItem=item;
  for(var x=1;x<=i;x++){
    id=item+"_"+x;
    document.getElementById(id).src="<?= suburl(); ?>/b.gif";
  }
  for(var x=i+1;x<=max;x++){
    id=item+"_"+x;
    if(x<=j)
      document.getElementById(id).src="<?= suburl(); ?>/y.gif";
    else document.getElementById(id).src="<?= suburl(); ?>/w.gif";
  }
}
```

I have tried with `<?= suburl(); ?>` and with `<?php echo suburl(); ?>`

Function suburl(); looks like this:

```
function suburl() {
  $suburl = 'http://localhost/www.site.com/static';
  echo $suburl;
}
```

And it's not working on echoing it in javascript. It appears like pure html.
It's much appreciated thank you.

Comment: You can't do that, PHP is server side, it won't be executed on your client. You can instead use PHP to print Javascript function with desired URL.

Comment: try `function suburl() {
  $suburl = 'http://localhost/www.site.com/static';
  return $suburl;
}`

Comment: Do you have this code on a `.php` page? Else it won't work.

Comment: @vonUbisch The php code it's located before this code and the js is located in a file script.js after the php code.

Comment: It's not very clear to me, but just to repeat; if there is any `<?=` or `<?php` in the file, the file extension MUST be .php or else the PHP won't parse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with something like this:

```
function showIt(item,i,j,max){
  var id;
  actualItem=item;
  var url = suburl(); //THIS IS NEW
  for(var x=1;x<=i;x++){
    id=item+"_"+x;
    document.getElementById(id).src=url+"/b.gif";
  }
  for(var x=i+1;x<=max;x++){
    id=item+"_"+x;
    if(x<=j)
      document.getElementById(id).src=url+"/y.gif";
    else document.getElementById(id).src=url+"/w.gif";
  }
}

function suburl() {
  var suburl = 'http://localhost/www.site.com/static';
  return suburl;
}
```

Answer (score -5):

```
function showIt(item,i,j,max){
var id;
actualItem=item;
for(var x=1;x<=i;x++){
id=item+"_"+x;
document.getElementById(id).src="<?= echo suburl(); ?>/b.gif";
}
for(var x=i+1;x<=max;x++){
  id=item+"_"+x;
  if(x<=j)
  document.getElementById(id).src="<?= echo suburl(); ?>/y.gif";
else document.getElementById(id).src="<?= echo suburl(); ?>/w.gif";
}
}
```

Function suburl(); looks like this:

```
function suburl() {
$suburl = 'http://localhost/www.site.com/static';
return $suburl;
}
```

Hope this Help.
Thanks

Comment: I hope you dont expect that this really works, do you?

Comment: I don't even see what you changed. Maybe you should describe what you did. Maybe.

Comment: he added echos in the php tags.

Comment: @YUNOWORK So his answer is bad **and** wrong. Nice.